# django cms apphook error

Tags: django, url, django-cms

I am learning django-cms. I tried to make custom plugin which was quite successful but when I tried to hook my custom made plugin to apphook, its giving me an error, saying,

> No Module named urls
>   .

I followed the tutorial which was given in django cms sites documentation, and created the cms_app.py file. Currently my application directory has all the files which is required to make a custom plugin for django cms, and an additional file of cms_app.py.

Is something wrong with setting of the url or do I need to create a new urls.py file inside my app directory?

My cms_app.py is exactly the same as given in the tutorial.

i have created a project called myproject using command -

> python django-admin.py startproject
>   myproject

After referring to the tutorial given for cms I created a plugin called first, using the basic command

> python manage.py startapp first

Now the plugin is working perfectly well, and the directory structure before making an attempt to the apphook was,

```
first/
    __init__.py
    cms_plugins.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Now after making an attempt to hook the app in apphook, the directory structure is:

```
first/
    __init__.py
    cms_app.py
    cms_plugins.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

My cms_app.py is as follows:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class FirstApp(CMSApp):
    name = _("First App") # give your app a name, this is required
    urls = ["first.urls"] # link your app to url configuration(s)

apphook_pool.register(FirstApp) # register your app
```

i have a urls.py file in myproject folder, and it is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^myproject/', include('myproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

I have restarted the server as was mentioned in the tutorial, but no success. 
Any ideas as to what is wrong with my simple app?!

**EDIT - 1**
My views file is as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    “””Generate the context for the main summary page”””
    return render_to_response(‘first/first.html’)
```

**Edit - 2**
I have changed my urls.py inside first app folder to this :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^myproject/', include('myproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^first/$', include('first.views.index')),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

But now I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError at /

Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/naveen/django_projects/myproject/first/views.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (views.py, line 4)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     SyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/naveen/django_projects/myproject/first/views.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (views.py, line 4)

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/naveen/django_projects/myproject',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.8.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']

Server time:    Thu, 31 Mar 2011 11:00:41 -0500
```

I have edited the urls and views but now I am getting this error.

```
NameError at /first/

global name 'render_to_response' is not defined

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/first/?preview
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

global name 'render_to_response' is not defined

Exception Location:     /home/naveen/django_projects/myproject/first/views.py in index, line 5
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/naveen/django_projects/myproject',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.8.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']

Server time:    Thu, 31 Mar 2011 14:50:32 -0500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a `first.urls` module with the URLs of your 'first' app. Next to your file `first/models.py`, create a file `first/urls.py` which contains the URL patterns for the 'first' app.

For the views you give in your questions, the urls.py should look something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from first.views import index

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', index),
)
```

Also note that in your views, you use non-standard quote characters, it should look like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    """Generate the context for the main summary page"""
    return render_to_response("first/first.html")
```

Comment: thanks for replying, can you show me what URL pattern should be there?! Sorry, I am really confused at this stage.

Comment: for that I would require to know more about the views in your app.

Comment: Theres nothing in my views file now. Its empty.

Comment: in this case there's no point in having an apphook. The reason behind apphooks is when you wish to hook views in your app onto a specific page (and under it).

Comment: I have added the views in the first app folder. I have edited my question.

Comment: now add a urls.py, read the django docs on how to do that if necessary

Comment: I did change the urls.py file. I have edited my question with the new urls.py file and error.

Comment: I changed the files as you have written. But now getting a different error. I have edited it in my question.

Comment: you don't import ``render_to_response`` in your views. No offense but you should probably first read http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/ before diving too deep into this